# Highcharter plotBands, plotLines with time series data

Tags: r, highcharts

What is the correct way to specify values in `highcharter` library's `plotLines` and `plotBands` when plotting time series? With the following code, plot line appears at the left end of chart and band does not appear at all. If I don't specify `type = 'stock'` even the plot line does not appear. This seems to be a problem with time series data only as with other type of data it works fine. So I believe I may not be specifying the value in correct format. Besides the one in code, I have tried the time series format e.g. `from = c(1990,1)` but it did not work either.

```
library(highcharter)    
data =ts(data = sample(c(50:100),360, replace = TRUE), start = c(1987,1), frequency = 12, names = 'index')

highchart(type = 'stock')%>%
      hc_add_series_ts(data) %>%
      hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime',
               plotLines = list(
                 list(
                   label = list(text = "This is a plotLine"),
                   color = "#FF0000",
                   width = 5,
                   value = as.Date('1990-01-01', tz = 'UTC')
                   )
                 ),
                 plotBands = list(
                   list(
                     label = list(text = "This is a plotBand"),
                     color = "rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                     from = as.Date('1995-01-01', tz = 'UTC'),
                     to = as.Date('1996-01-01', tz = 'UTC')
                     )
                   )
               )
```

This is the resulting chart
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your date values need to be transformed using `datetime_to_timestamp` function.

This is, from :

```
 from = as.Date('1995-01-01', tz = 'UTC'),
 to = as.Date('1996-01-01', tz = 'UTC')
```

To:

```
 from = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('1995-01-01', tz = 'UTC')),
 to = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('1996-01-01', tz = 'UTC'))
```

Details:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(highcharter))
dt <- as.Date("1995-01-01", tz = "UTC")
dt
#> [1] "1995-01-01"
datetime_to_timestamp(dt)
#> [1] 788918400000
```

Hope this helps.

[image: output]